# Flatten array of items into the middle of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like so

```
let items = [
  {name: "1"},
  {name: "2"},
  {name: "3"},
  {unwrap: true,
    items: [
      {name: "4"},
      {name: "5"},
      {name: "6"},
    ]
  },
  {name: "7"},
]
```

How can I flatten the unwrap object to get the following output?

```
items = [
  {name: "1"},
  {name: "2"},
  {name: "3"},
  {name: "4"},
  {name: "5"},
  {name: "6"},
  {name: "7"},
]
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
items.map(item => {
  if(item.hasOwnProperty("unwrap")){
    return ... item.items
  }
  return item
})
```

However the `...`s don't work as a return value.

I have come up with the somewhat clunky using a second array like so:

```
let output = []
items.forEach((item) => {
    if (!item) {
        return;
    }
    if (item.hasOwnProperty("unwrap")) {
        return output.push(...item.contents);
    }
    return output.push(item);
});
```

Comment: You have to wrap it in array, like`return [... item.items]`. 
You can also do something like this `items.map(o => o.items ? o.items : o).flat()`

Comment: use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead of `map`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is what you need.

```js
const items=[{name:"1"},{name:"2"},{name:"3"},{unwrap:!0,items:[{name:"4"},{name:"5"},{name:"6"}]},{name:"7"}];

const result = items.flatMap(item => {
  if (item.hasOwnProperty('unwrap')) {
    return item.items;
  }
  return item;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can rely on `flatMap`:

```
items.flatMap((x) => {
  if (!x.unwrap) {
    return x;
  }

  return x.items;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let items = [{name: "1"}, {name: "2"}, {name: "3"}, {unwrap: true, items: [{name: "4"}, {name: "5"}, {name: "6"}, ] }, {name: "7"}, ];

const res = items.reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c.items || c), []);

console.log(res);
```

Since `obj.items` won't exist on the regular objects, we can use the `||` operator to get the desired items, then `concat` those to the final array.

Answer (score 0):

another way is:

```
items.flatMap(item=> item?.unwrap ? item.items: item )
```

or

```
const result = items.flatMap(item=> item?.unwrap ? item.items: item )
```